# Changing Authentication from individual accounts to Windows (Intranet) in ASP.Net MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have an ASP.Net MVC 5 site that was originally setup to use individual accounts for authentication. This app now needs to be move to an intranet and use Windows authentication.

What needs to be removed from the original app to make it work with windows authentication only? I've tried just changing the authentication method in the web.config but the app still tries to go to the Account/Login pages and still has all the OWin stuff trying to start up. So I am assuming that a bunch of startup code needs to be removed also. I've started removing files that seem to be involved but that has become a bit of a rabbit hole.

Anyone know of an article explaining the process or have any suggestions on the steps needed?

Comment: Check Global.asax.cs file. most of the warm up is done there before request reaches the controller.

Comment: I found a reference to adding 
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false"/> to the web.config. That seemed to do the trick without me having to remove a bunch of code files.

Comment: @JohnS But now you've got a bunch of useless code files in your application. It would be better to actually remove the files from your project rather than disabling OWIN.

Comment: I agree @mason, good point.

Answer (score 4):

I have a suggestion for you, Create two empty applications one based on individual account and other based on windows authentication
then compare these two projects with comparison tools like winmerge (compare project folders)
and apply the changes to your project.
for example replace

```
<authentication mode="None"/>
```

with this

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

and remove

```
<modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
</modules>
```

Comment: @Ahmedilyas How is that a maintenance headache? It's a one-time expense to compare the difference between a Identity and Windows authentication.

Comment: it was not made clear that it is a one time expense.... if you are creating 2 separate apps that do the same thing with 1 small difference then really it is a maintenance headache.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I suggest you delete the comment saying that it's a maintenance headache if you've misunderstood what the answer is saying, because it may give someone the wrong impression of what the answer entails. As the answer describes it, you're only creating two different applications so that you can learn what the difference is between applications. There is *no additional maintenance*, just a one time thing to do for learning's sake.